# 'be fit for', 'fit', or 'be fitting for' what is the correct usage and why?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

After checking the old post, I found this [Difference between 'it fits something' and 'it is fit for something' -- "The key fits the lock" vs. "The key is fit for the lock"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72587/difference-between-it-fits-something-and-it-is-fit-for-something-the-key) quite informative. However, I still have some doubts on fit.

What is the exact difference of below 2 sentences, or are they identical?

1. The resume is fit for the position.
2. The resume fits the position.

In spoken English, do native people say: 'this guy is fitting for the job', and 'this guy is fitting the job'?

Comment: I guess it is nicer to show the effort you'd already made. For example, when I am not sure the usage of a word, I usually look up the definition/explanation and examples [on a dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/) or other trusted reference. And then I might ask some question based on that. That would help answerers know what you've understood and what not.

Answer (score -1):

The two sentences are nearly identical, the only nuance is that #2 is a bit stronger. You imply that the *whole* resume fits. "the resume is fit for" means that it satisfies all your basic criteria.

As for the use of "fitting", the -ing end is used very sparingly in English as someone has to be actively doing something right now before it is used. So in 99% of cases you would use use "fits the job" or "fit for the job".

You could use "is fitting for the job" if you are holding his resume and discussing it with a coworker but if you are unsure of your English: just avoid -ing because ususally you won't need it.

Comment: Thanks for the great clarification! Can I also say 'this guy fits for the job'?

Comment: yes, but only really if you want to contast it to some who doesn't fit. Well the other candidate is not suitable but *this* guy fits for the job.

Comment: Great answer. thanks Borgh!

Comment: This is incorrect.  You can't use *fitting* as you have used it.